# Which is the estimate for the next exponent giving a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The triple $$(a,b,c)=(249,343,847)$$ is the unique triple of integers $a,b,c$ satisfying $\ 0<a<b<c<1000\ $ with the property that $$a^n+b^n+c^n$$ has no prime factor below $\ 100\ $ for every positive integer $\ n\ $

Primes occur for $$n=0,1,2,3,5,6,7,50,82,546$$ for the last $\ n\ $ I did not yet prove the primality. Currently, my search limit is $\ n=2\ 000\ $

> Based on the search limit and considering that we never have a prime factor below $\ 100\ $, which estimate for the next $\ n\ $ giving a prime does the $\ 1/ln(x)\ $-approach give ?

Comment: I have extended my search to $n=\ 3\ 000\ $ , but for the question , the limit $\ 2\ 000\ $ can be used as well.

Comment: Thank you for the obligatory downvote .

Comment: For those interested, the actual value of the next exponent is $\ 4\ 905\ $